# Why is pkexec preferred over gksudo for graphical applications?

Tags: sudo, pkexec

Please provide Ubuntu documentation that refutes this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Why, on my fully updated 13.04 system, does `pkexec` not function?

```
$ pkexec gedit somefile.txt
No protocol specified

** (gedit:13135): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Cannot open display: 
Run '/usr/bin/gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options
```

Comment: I just realized this is the same question you asked earlier. I think what Salem meant was you should ask what to use since pkexec doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: I know what to use: gksudo. That's what I posted in my original answer that was incorrectly edited to pkexec. Although the edit stated that pkexec was preferred, I am unable to find any evidence that it is. I have no idea why it is stated to be preferred since it doesn't actually work! If anyone, especially the original editor, has any Ubuntu documentation showing that it is, I am anxious to read it.

Comment: Right, I understand. Have you seen this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6634/psa-gksu-is-no-longer-installed-by-default ? gksu ins't included in 13.04 so we need to eventually switch to something else if possible. Another thing to read is http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application

Comment: Is gksudo included? I never referred to gksu.

Comment: gksudo and gksu are pretty much the same thing. gksudo is just a symlink to gksu. So my guess is no.

Comment: In fact, gksu and gksudo are installed by default in 13.04 as you can see here from a live CD session I downloaded just now: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/gksudo.png Even if they were not, in my opinion, it's a very poor solution to ask users to substitute pkexec which doesn't actually even work or even worse, to edit 30-40 lines of code into some polkit actions file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9456/discussion-between-chili555-and-seth)

Comment: Gksu is available in live media but is not installed (pretty much like Gparted). While there are some issues with pkexec, it is still installed by default and that probably is the reason to prefer it over gksu.

Comment: Anyway, let's not keep multiple instances of the same question around. I'll close it as a duplicate of the other question for preserving sanity.

Comment: "...some issues with pkexec..."??? It doesn't actually work! That's a pretty big issue, don't you think?